# Odd error with casting to timestamp in standard SQL/Tableau

Tags: sql, csv, google-bigquery, tableau-api

The latest version of Tableau has started using standard SQL when it connects to Google's BigQuery.

I recently tried to update a large table but found that there appeared to be errors when trying to parse datetimes. The table originates as a CSV which is loaded into BigQuery where further manipulations happen. The datetime column in the original CSV contain strings in ISO standard date time format (basically yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm). This saves a lot of annoying manipulation later.

But on trying to convert the datetime strings in Tableau into dates or datetimes I got a bunch of errors. On investigation they seemed to come from BigQuery and looked like this:

```
Error: Invalid timestamp: '2015-06-28 02:01'
```

I thought at first this might be a Tableau issue so I loaded a chunk of the original CSV into Tableau directly where the conversion of the string to a data worked perfectly well.

I then tried simpler versions of the conversion (to a year rather than a full datetime) and they still failed. The generated SQL for the simplest conversion looks like this:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    CAST(`Arrival_Date` AS TIMESTAMP)) AS `yr_Arrival_Date_ok`
FROM
  `some_dataset`.`some_table` `some_table`
GROUP BY
  1
```

The invalid timestamp in the error message always looks to me like a perfectly valid timestamp. And further analysis suggests it doesn't happen for *all* the rows in the source table, just occasional ones.

This error did not appear in older versions of Tableau/BigQuery where legacy SQL was the default for Tableau. So i'm presuming it is a consequence of standard SQL.

So is there an intermittent problem with casting to timestamps in BigQuery? Or is this a Tableau problem which causes the SQL to be incorrectly formatted? And what can I do about it?

Comment: I'm sure if you sent this info to tableau support, they would be keen to work on fixing it

Answer (score 1):

The seconds part in the [canonical timestamp representation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type) required if the hour and minute are also present. Try this instead with `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` and see if it works:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR
    FROM
      PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %R', `Arrival_Date`)) AS `yr_Arrival_Date_ok`
FROM
  `some_dataset`.`some_table`.`some_table`
GROUP BY
  1
```

Comment: I can't control the SQL: that's generated by Tableau. And I have seen the same error even when seconds are present. I will experiment directly in BigQuery for more detail and report to Tableau support.